# what documents should we bring for interview

Tags: interviewing, resume, new-job

I read an article on [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/lisaquast/2013/07/29/are-you-bringing-the-right-documents-to-job-interviews-find-out/) discussing the things we should bring to the interview.

What documents should we carry while going for the interview? Should I bring my design portfolio? What about original documents?

The question is in reference to a job in an IT department.

Comment: You should carry the documents you think you will use.  Without an industry there is no objective way to answer this question.

Comment: I asked in reference to IT industry..i have mentioned

Comment: downvoter please comment for downvote..or suggest an answer

Comment: @divya, I've edited your question to make it more concise and suitable for The Workplace. I hope that's ok.

Comment: There are hundreds of different types of jobs in the IT industry. Each one may have differing needs and each company may want something differnt.

Comment: The question is still pretty vague.  This should be indicated by the company (which makes it company specific), you likely should NOT bring any sort of portfolio without asking the company first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently was hired on in IT in December. To my interview, I brought:

- Copies of my resume. I knew I was getting interviewed by 4 people, so I brought 5 copies in case anyone needed one.
- A copy of the job posting. I reviewed this before going in to the interview. Waiting time, etc.
- Notes I'd made about the company from online research, and subsequent questions I was prepared to ask my interviewers. Prepare to ask about the company as well as technical aspects of the job. I also reviewed these quickly before the interview.
- A pen

Since your interview sounds like it could be different from mine, I'd recommend bringing that design portfolio. Either have it printed or have it as a website ([wix](http://www.wix.com) has nice and free templates). It sounds like a graphic or web design job, so I'd definitely bring those items. If it's programming, bring code samples. If you do bring samples, bring only 3 or 4, the ones that most showcase your skills and understanding of the job you'll be doing.

Most importantly, bring all of this in a folio-type notebook. I used a legal pad holder with a pocket on the inside. I kept all of my items in the pocket, with the job listing in front. This way, you can have everything on you, take notes on your own paper, and look prepared and professional.